# C# Find Text After Word In Textbox

Tags: c#, string, substring

I'm having some trouble finding how to word this problem in Google, so was hoping I could explain it here and get some help please.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter & InputTextbox.Text.Contains("in"))
{
    string textT = InputTextbox.Text;
    string sub = "";
    sub = textT.Substring(textT.IndexOf("in"));
    MessageBox.Show("The town is: " + sub);
}
```

So, what I am trying to do is get the user to type in "How is the weather today in Sydney", or whatever town they choose.

How do I get the name of whatever town they are writing after the "in" text? At the moment the code I have is returning "in Sydney".

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substring will return the index of "In" so you need to skip 3 characters.

```
sub = textT.Substring(textT.IndexOf("in") + 3);
```

Comment: This is true but substring is a hacky way to do this. Wouldn't you suggest a regex instead?

Comment: @AMR I guess there isn't a perfect solution here mainly because the detection is pretty simple and is not really accounting for every possible input like "How is the weather in Sydney in the evening". In that case both regex and substring will not work.

Comment: @AMR As much as I like regex, I don't see why that would be an improvement in this case.

Comment: It actually needs to be a "+3" to skip the "i", "n" and " " space.

Comment: var preface = "in ";
textT.Substring(textT.IndexOf(preface) + preface.Length));